# Same as above checkbox option in ASP Web Application

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, checkbox

I want to implement the checkbox which on clicking will copy the text value of 5 one textbox to other textbox.

This is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    function SameAsMailing() {
        document.getElementById('<%= txtMName.ClientID %>').value = document.getElementById('<%= txtCName.ClientID %>').value;
    }
</script>
<input type="checkbox" name="chkSameAsMailing" id="chkSameAsMailing" onclick="SameAsMailing(this)" />
```

Comment: In what way is this code not working?  Does the JavaScript function execute?  Are there any errors on the browser console?  Are the elements found?  Where does it fail?

Comment: The javascript does not execute. I corrected the syntax but still not working

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your JavaScript, you never closed the `ready` handler or the call to the `ready()` function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function SameAsMailing() {
        document.getElementById('<%= txtMName.ClientID %>').value = document.getElementById('<%= txtCName.ClientID %>').value;
    }
}); // <-- missing this
```

Comment: @UrwishPatel: Define "not working".  Use your browser's debugging tools.  "Not working" could mean *anything*.  Maybe jQuery isn't loaded?  Maybe there's another error preventing the JavaScript from executing?  Maybe the elements aren't found?  You need to debug this.

Comment: I used the debugging tool. Turns out the jQuery was not getting loaded because of linking issue. Thanks for the input though.